# Pytesseract - using .traineddata file on hosted server (Heroku)

Tags: django, heroku, fonts, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have a Vue, Django integrated project. I hosted the Vue project on Netlify and the Django project on Heroku. A python script (integrated into Heroku) is called on certain buttons which extract data and posts this to the Django API to be viewed on the frontend.

I have trained a font type for my pytesseract OCR script. However, when i run it on Heroku, it seems like i can only use the 'eng' (normal font) as 'language' for my pytesseract image_to_string function. If I have the .traineddata file of the font type that I want to use, how can I use this file within the pytesseract functions? I can call the individual file, but I need the right TESSDATA_PREFIX as well. Does someone know how to deal with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It is olved by setting TESSDATA_PREFIX Config Var to a custom directory and inserting all .traineddata files to that directory.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).